# how to convert input date to unix (php) time

Tags: php, php-5.5

How do you convert an input date like 01/16/2013 to a time format similar to 1422424719. Whats the best way to compare these two time stamp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('01/16/2013');
```

Just compare them as you would do with any other variable. <, >, = ... are all available

Also check the [PHP manual for the DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php). It will make handling dates and times easier.

Comment: thank you, guess thinking about hours and minutes which can be drawn from time() threw me off track. thanks for the refresher. i need some sleep. lol